# How can I disable the suspend to disk function on my MacBook Pro

Tags: mac, macos

Whenever I close the lid of my MacBook Pro it takes over a minute to write out my memory to disk. This is part of the Mac's *safe* suspend option, which allows it to restore your memory from the hibernation file if the Mac loses power (say you change batteries or they go flat) while it is asleep.

I prefer my machine to go to sleep as soon as possible and am willing to take the risk of an unclean shutdown should my battery go flat.

A long time ago I disabled this behavior, but have recently reinstalled my machine and OS X has reverted to the default behavior.

How can I disable the hibernation action when I close the lid?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To disable Safe Sleep:

```
$ sudo pmset -a hibernatemode 0
$ sudo nvram "use-nvramrc?"=false
```

Further details can be found at http://www.normalesup.org/~martinez/macosx/, Including how to enable it again.

Answer (score 7):

I use the [SmartSleep](http://www.jinx.de/SmartSleep.html) preference pane.